# Is combination of words "Smarten digital" wrong if used as company name?

Tags: meaning, phrases

We are discussinng possible name of new european SW company and now we are considering something like "smarten digital". I know, that werb "smarten" is usualy used with "up", so my question is: Is "smarten digital" wrong as company name? We are not native english and the word "smarten" is in this case result of our surnames combinations... Does "smarten digital" sound weird to EN speaking people?

Comment: It's weird. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: If it's some kind of app or electronic developer I'd say use "Smart N Digital" or some such. You could advertise by saying something like "enhance digital solutions with Smart N and 'smarten' up your network". To me Smarten Digital sounds odd, but so did naming an online supermarket after female warriors of renown. If 'Amazon' works as a name there's no reason 'Smarten' can't.

Comment: You can use anything you want as a company name, short of something that is somehow obscene or libelous or which infringes on another's mark.

Comment: For a company called *Smarten Digital*, I would think 'Smarten' was a last name.

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with **any** company name, from an English point of view. Company names are proper nouns. English has nothing to say about what you name your company. Name it "*iuhwn owete w87@%# #^nnnns;h*", for all English cares.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound weird, because EN speaking people will hear it as "Smart 'n' Digital" if they don't see it in front of them. You are right to hesitate that in print, with no context, "Smarten" doesn't jump out as the word, but rather as a possible proper noun.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's going to sound weird. Not actually ungrammatical, but definitely weird. The reason is that *smarten* is usually a transitive verb) though often the object is *yourself*, which can be omitted), and so the reader will expect the word after it to be a noun. Instead you have an adverb which has no visible relationship to the verb, and you leave the question 'Is the object of *smarten* yourself or your company or...?' unanswered.

Things are not helped by your attempt to use *digital*, an adjective, as an adverb. This is clearly ungrammatical, but equally clearly it is sometimes done, particularly in advertising. I have no wish to provoke another round of this wearisome argument, since most arguers' certainty is matched only by their lack of evidence; merely to say that here it adds unnecessary uncertainty and strangeness.

Comment: But weird isn't usually wrong as these things go.